# How to remember location for functions if page is reloaded after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a short jquery for a Drupal 8 website - if the user scrolls down the page, the header background changes color. But, if the user has scrolled down the page already, **then reloads the page, the header div reverts to the original color.** It no longer is aware of the page being at a lower position. It won't change again until the user has scrolled.

How can I rework this script so that the page location is known on reload and the script acts accordingly.

```
(function ($) {
   $(document).scroll(function () {
      var $header = $(".headerbox");
      $header.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $header.height());     

      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 81) {
            $('#block-branding a img').attr('src','/themes/custom/logo-white.svg');
            $('.headerwrap').css('height','7em');
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 80) {
            $('#block-branding a img').attr('src','/themes/custom/logo.svg');
            $('.headerwrap').css('height','10em');
        }
      });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the header update into a function and also call it onload.

```js
(function ($) {
   function updateHeader() {
      //console.log($(this).scrollTop());
      var $header = $(".headerbox");
      $(".headerwrap").toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $header.height());
      
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > $header.height()) {
        //$('#block-branding a img').attr('src','/themes/custom/logo-white.svg');
        $('.headerwrap').css('height','7em');
      } else {
        //$('#block-branding a img').attr('src','/themes/custom/logo.svg');
        $('.headerwrap').css('height','10em');
      }
   }
   $(document).scroll(updateHeader);
   window.onload = updateHeader();
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.headerwrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
}

.headerbox {
  padding: 8px;
}

.scrolled {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="headerwrap">
  <h1 class="headerbox">Header</h1>
</header>
<body onclick="window.location.reload()" style="margin: 0; margin-top: 10em; padding: 8px;">
  <h1>Body</h1>
  <p>
    body
    <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
    <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
    <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
    <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
    <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
    <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
    <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
  </p>
</body>
```